# Is Invalidate Caches and Restart a remedy for bugs?

Tags: android, android-studio

My *Android Studio* is updated (3.4.1). My computer is operating with  *Windows 7* with 8GB RAM.

I'm having some strange problems inside *Android Studio*. The last is that the program didn't was recognizing string values in `strings.xml` inside the program

I check this in debugger. I saw weird negative values.

My solution, one more time, was run `Invalidate Caches and Restart`. After that, everything works again. It's very weird.

What can be happening?

Comment: probably wrong permissions on the user's home directory, where the Gradle cache is located.

Comment: My home directory for my project is `c:\Users\paulo\AndroidStudioProjects\YourCalcs`. The gradle folder is here. There are no restrictions in all user tree. My user name is `Paulo`

Comment: this is not the Gradle home ...

Comment: I've done a pure `Android Studio` instalation. `Gradle` is bundled inside `Android Studio`. My Gradle was installed in `c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle` and the plugin was in `c:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\gradle`. This folders usually are not used for write data in Windows, except by special permission.

Comment: In `Android Studio`, i go to menu`File`,  `Settings`,  `Build, Execution, Deployment`, `Gradle`. The option `Use default gradle wrapper`   is `on`, and `gradle home` field is empty.  The option `using explicit module group`  is `on`

Answer (score 1):

NO. `AndroidStudio` caches a great number of files and does not delete them. Therefore, the system cache may one day become overloaded and then you'll have to clear these cache files manually by yourself and restart `AndroidStudio`. Hence, the name  **Invalidate Caches and Restart**

Below is the link for more reference.

[Cleaning System Cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html?origin=old_help)

Comment: Ok, I know it, but it does not explain the bugs in `Android Studio`. It's an erratic behaviour. It would be much more civilized for `Android Studio` to give a message like: `Full cache, please reboot and clear the cache here`